# jquery Datatables checkbox get all checked rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have a datatable in which in which I'm trying to get all the checked rows. This table has row grouping and uses a checkbox plugin from [gyrocode](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/). I've tried the code listed on the [api](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/reference/api/), but I had no luck. I only get the first record returned, regardless of what is selected. The code I used for the  is shown below:

```
var tbl;
$(document).ready(function (){
          tbl = $('#example').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 0,
                data: 2,
                'checkboxes': {
                    'selectRow': true
                }
            },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 1 }],
            select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },
            order: [[1, 'asc']],
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            drawCallback: function () {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                var last = null;

                api.column(1, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                    if (last !== group) {
                        $(rows).eq(i).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="6">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                        );
                        last = group;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});

function getSelected(){
    alert(tbl.columns().checkboxes.selected().length);
}
```

I have the code in my [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jgvpLzo/7/) here. I'm not sure if their is interence between the checkbox and the row grouping? Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Note: The checkbox is based on the plugin by gyrocode The datatables is version 1.10.12

Comment: So what is the problem?Not very clear in your question

Comment: It seems to be working actually, if you do `console.log(tbl.columns().checkboxes.selected())`, you can see that there is an array that contains the unique, selected student ids. If you use different Ids per row, i can see it working. The `length` property is not what you want.

Comment: You need to use `column(0).checkboxes.selected()` instead. Also you have duplicate ids in the table which affects the total count.

Comment: That works as well. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a quick check and Eric Guan is correct. I'll just post a code snippet:

```
function getSelected() {
   var selectedIds = tbl.columns().checkboxes.selected()[0];
   console.log(selectedIds)

   selectedIds.forEach(function(selectedId) {
       alert(selectedId);
   });
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/nwmmbLso/3/

I just noticed you have duplicatie Student Id's which might also cause unexpected behavior from the library you are using. The code provided above should work if the Student Id's are unique.

Comment: I'm the author of the mentioned plug-in. Good answer and point about duplicate IDs. However recommended method is to use `column(0).checkboxes.selected()` if only one column data is accessed, although your code would work too.

Comment: It was the [0], that I wasn't aware of. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: See this jsbin for getting row node and all checked rows across all pages of datatable. http://live.datatables.net/mutavegi/34/edit

Answer (score 11):

I'm too late to answer this question. But my answer can help others in the community.

```
//datatable has to be initialized to a variable
var myTable = $('#calltable').dataTable();

//checkboxes should have a general class to traverse
var rowcollection = myTable.$(".call-checkbox:checked", {"page": "all"});

//Now loop through all the selected checkboxes to perform desired actions
rowcollection.each(function(index,elem){
    //You have access to the current iterating row
    var checkbox_value = $(elem).val();
    //Do something with 'checkbox_value'
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: this code resolved my issue of not getting all the ids of checked box across all pages. just to state the obvious in above code [.call-checkbox] is a class which needs to be appended when table data generated.

Comment: Thanks that really help me, im strugling finding the answer that suits my code, this one help big ups to you

Answer (score 4):

**Working and tested.**

```
      var id = "";
      var oTable = $(".table").dataTable();

      $(".check_quality:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function() {
          if (id != "") {
              id = id + "," + $(this).data('id');
          } else {
              id = $(this).data('id');
          }
      });
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include some explanation of how this code answers the question, to provide context to future users. A code block by itself is not immediately useful to those who would come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - use either table.rows( '.selected' ) or table.rows( {selected:true} )

```
var count = $('#datatable').DataTable().rows( '.selected' ).count();

var checked_rows = $('#datatable').DataTable().rows( '.selected' ).data();

for(var i=0; i<checked_rows.length; i++)
{
  console.log( checked_rows[i] );               
}
```

Document Link: https://datatables.net/reference/api/count()

Answer (score 0):

for people still looking today for the answer

```
var rowcollection = table.columns(0).context[0].checkboxes.s.data;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).